# Polymorphic this in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to do what I think is a "textbook" use case for polymorphic `this` and it isn't working and I just can't figure this out.  Imagine I have some `abstract` base class that is cloneable, e.g.:

```
abstract class X {
    abstract clone(): this;
}
```

Now I want to implement a base class that provides a `clone` implementation:

```
class Y extends X {
    constructor(private x: number) { super() }
    clone(): this { return new Y(this.x + 1); }
}
```

When I do this, I get an error that says `Type Y is not assignable to type 'this'`.  I'm totally confused.  All I want to convey here is the type constraint that if a subclass of `X` has its `clone` method invoked, that the type of the thing that you will get back will be identical to the subtype.  Isn't this exactly what polymorphic `this` is for?  What am I doing wrong here?

[Here is a link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20clone()%3A%20this%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Y%20extends%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20x%3A%20number)%20%7B%20super()%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clone()%3A%20this%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Y(this.x%20%2B%201)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) to this code in the TypeScript playground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as things are right now, it's not a supported use case for this type. A method with `this` return type should return an instance of derived class even if this method is not overridden in the derived class - see [code in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40503707/43848) for an example that justifies this.

In other words, given `abstract clone(): this` declaration, this code must be valid even if Z does not override `clone` itself, but you implementation of `clone` in `Y` breaks it.

```
class Z extends Y {
    f() {
        let c: Z = this.clone();
    }
}
```

So it looks like a method with `this` return type should always `return this`.

UPDATE: I found an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/283#issuecomment-194034654) with this use case on github, marked as 'accepting pull requests'. I'm not sure however if they really intend to support it, or plan to fix `cloneNode` in their compiler in some other way.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I see what you mean.  But it is odd you say it is "not a supported use case" since it is explicitly mentioned (although not actually implemented) in the PR for this feature in the compiler https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910

Comment: Well, that PR was merged more than a year ago, and it's been 6 months since the issue where they supposedly want to fix this use case was marked as 'accepting PRs'. I added words to the effect that this use case is not currently supported. If they really wanted to support it it would have been fixed long ago.

Comment: I've provided an alternative answer that includes an unsafe workaround.

Answer (score 5):

I've marked artem's answer as the correct one because he seems to be correct that it really isn't possible to do this in a 100% safe way.

However, there is a way to get the compiler to enforce the type constraint I wanted.  So, I decided to include this answer in case it is useful to people.  The only downside of my approach is that it is slightly unsafe for exactly the reasons that artem points out, i.e., that somebody could extend your classes without providing an implementation of `clone` and create a situation where the returned value would not really be what you claim it is.

My solution was to just add a cast.  Again, this is unsafe in general.  But if you never extend from the classes, it works fine as far as I can tell.  So my solution was:

```
class Y extends X {
    constructor(private x: number) { super() }
    clone(): this {
        return new Y(this.x + 1) as this;
    }
}
```

You can see a complete version that compiles [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abstract%20clone()%3A%20this%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Y%20extends%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20x%3A%20number)%20%7B%20super()%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clone()%3A%20this%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Y(this.x%20%2B%201)%20as%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A).